# Pull session id of name django

Tags: django, python-2.7

Issue im having is i have two aps a login app that gets all the info the apps are working just fine. I am trying to set a session that displays the person name that logged in. But I cant get it to display. When I run the login app by itself not in another app it works. I believe it has something to do with the two apps together. I can pull a name with a for loop as such

```
{% for i in info %} 
<h1>Hello {{ i.creator.name }}!</h1> 
{% endfor %}
```

However that just gives me the first name in the list of people registered not the name of the person logged in.  Currently {{ request.session.name }} is how I have it now. Which works when single app. Is there a trick to it when going from app to app?

I have uninstalled django and reinstalled to fix any corruptions in middle ware I have made sure the defaults are all there. I even pulled up other apps I have made with same login and those work. I have copied that code to make sure and still this app will not pull the session of name from the model.

Any other ideas would be great.

```
Index.html 


<h1>Hello {{ request.session.name }}!</h1> 

view.py

def index(request):
    context = {

    'info':Myblackbelt.objects.all()


    }
    print(Myblackbelt.objects.all())
    return render(request, 'blackbeltapp/index.html', context)

models

from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from ..logReg.models import User


class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def add_product(self, postData, user): 
    product = postData.get('product', None) 
    if product is not None and user: 
        Myblackbelt = self.create(product=product, creator=user)





class Myblackbelt(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length = 70)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    loguser = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='loguser')
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='creator')


    objects = ProductManager()
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about different apps. You only have one app here, and accessing the logged-in user has nothing to do with what app your view is in. You can access the username in the template via `{{ request.user.username }}`.

Comment: No that does not work at all. Have just tried again even change it with name which is also in model and no